# Linq - Using GroupBy with my own type vs anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects I want to group with Linq. The objects type is GroupRating. I want to group them by their "Params" property.

```
public class GroupRating
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Parameters Params { get; set; }
}

public class Parameters
{
    public int CarrierId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

The thing is that this works:
(ie. I get only one group with all the ids)

```
        var myList = new List<GroupRating>();
        ... blahblah code...

        var groupedList = myList.GroupBy(i => new {
             CarrierId = i.Params.CarrierId,
             CustomerId = i.Params.CustomerId
         }, i => i.Id).ToArray();
```

But this doesn't work:
(ie. I get as many groups as there is Ids)

```
        var myList = new List<GroupRating>();
        ... blahblah code...

        var groupedList = myList.GroupBy(i => new Params {
             CarrierId = i.Params.CarrierId,
             CustomerId = i.Params.CustomerId
         }, i => i.Id).ToArray();
```

Any idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `class` must override `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()` correctly. Otherwise two `new Params { ... }` will not be "equal" even if they look the same.

Anonymous types override these two methods automatically.

You could also use a `struct` instead of a `class` because a `struct` uses the overrides of `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()` that exist in `System.ValueType`. If you choose a `struct`, consider making the type *immutable*, i.e. make the properties read-only (or with `private set;`).

---

**Later addition:** Starting in 2020 (C# 9), you should use a `record` type if you want to make it easy for yourself. Then the C# compiler automatically generates `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()` implementations for you that match your exact needs in each case (no reflection). Since 2021 (C# 10), you can also choose `record struct` if you want a value-type record.

Comment: +1, but… A. The default `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in structs is far from optimal, so I'd recommend overriding them even if using a struct, and B. it's always worth considering immutability when possible, even in classes.

Comment: @JonHanna I agree with that (although, how inefficient can `ValueType`'s implementation be in the particular case where the struct has only two non-static fields both of which have type `int`?).

Comment: About as inefficient as it could be without being completely insane :) It reflects, and it reflects pretty well, and I'm all for reflection for fun and profit, but I'd still recommend overriding equality on any struct bar private types you know you'll never compare for equality.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You must use class or anonymous type.Params is not class.You can use it.

Try this:

```
  var groupedList = myList.GroupBy(i => new Parameters {
                 CarrierId = i.CarrierId,
                 CustomerId = i.CustomerId
             }, i => i.Id).ToArray();
```